# apt-get fails: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found

Tags: debian, apt, https

I tried to update my OS Debian jessie using the terminal  and i get an error :

```
“E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.” error?
```

My sources.list :

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main
```

How to fix `apt-get update` and `aptitude update`?

Comment: Keep in mind that there's no integrity benefit to using HTTPS since packages have signatures that are verified anyway - which is probably even better since you're not trusting many independent CAs. THere ay be some privacy benefit. See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90227/why-there-is-no-https-transport-for-debian-apt-tool

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Sounds like you may have added some https sources.  Since there are no https sources in your `sources.list`, it would be something in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

You may also be dealing with a proxy that always redirects to https.

You can add support for https apt sources by installing a couple of packages:

```
apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates
```

If your `apt-get` is too broken to do this, you can [download the package directly](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/apt-transport-https) and install it with `dpkg -i`.  Any additional dependencies of that package can be tracked down and fetched similarly (`dpkg` will let you know if anything is missing).

If it still doesn't work, you might try editing the source entry to use http instead of https, or just remove it and start over following the source maintainer's instructions.

Comment: For me, installing "apt-transport-https" and "ca-certificates" didn't fix the issue, but updating the files in "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/" (for me it was nodesource.list) to use http instead of https fixed it

Comment: `sudo dpkg -i <deb for apt-transport-https>` worked for me, but that install had dependencies that I had to fix with `apt-get update`, which the package install for apt-transport-https allowed me to perform.

Comment: "Unable to locate package apt-transport-https"

Comment: This totally fixed it for me! Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: For me it actually turned out that an *http* source was the cause of the above issue. Removing the corresponding file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` fixed it.

Comment: Or it could be that one of those http sources (which are clearly redirectors with a name like `httpredir`) redirects to https.

Comment: Using windows 11, I had installed Linux Debian Distribution. Followed this [docker installation guideline](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/) to install docker, it gave me OP's error after updating sources.list.d when I ran `sudo apt-get update`. This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

For me this issue happened because one of the mirrors happened to always redirect to https.
So none of my sources were https, but due to the redirect, apt would end up trying to fetch something off an https site.
To resolve this, I had to manually download and install:

- **libcurl3-gnutls** and
- **apt-transport-https**

(apt-transport-https had a dependency on libcurl3-gnutls).

Once those were installed, I was able to successfully install any other package, even if the mirror was on https.

Comment: In particular if you already have something on the system that can do the https download (`wget` , `curl`, a browser), you can do e.g. `apt install --print-uris apt-transport-https` to show the package URI, download the URI with something to get the `.deb`, and then install the `.deb` with e.g. `sudo dpkg -i apt-transport-https_1.0.9.8.6_amd64.deb`.

Answer (score 4):

There are few possible incidents which lead to this type of issues. The most likely solution would be to run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install apt-transport-https
```

You can find more details and possible causes for this issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165676/how-do-i-fix-a-e-the-method-driver-usr-lib-apt-methods-http-could-not-be-foun).

Comment: In Docker when this comes up you'll often need to run this BEFORE you add the source which uses https, or the `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` will fail due to inability to read from https.

Answer (score 3):

First check

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d# ls -l

insgesamt 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 142 Okt 12 14:12 jtaylor-keepass-jessie.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 332 Okt 12 14:07 sources.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  85 Okt 12 14:13 ubuntuzilla.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  78 Okt  8 09:13 ubuntuzilla.list.save
```

Remove all other let only `sources.list`

edit `sources.list`

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d# cat sources.list 
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main    
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates contrib main   
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates contrib main  
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates contrib main
```

try again:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If this did't work then install over browser:

to select a package:

```
http://security-cdn.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/a/apt/
```

or

```
http://security-cdn.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/a/apt/apt-transport-https_1.0.9.8.5_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

The link to an **https** source can also come from an http reference in your /etc/apt/sources.list file.

My sources.list :

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
..
deb [arch=armhf] http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian/ stretch main
```

included a reference to another source that in turn had an **https** reference.
Commenting out the following :

```
deb [arch=armhf] http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian/ stretch main
```

was the fix that worked for me.