# Debian 9 Stretch: unable to locate winehq-staging

Tags: debian, wine

I've done all these without any errors:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
$ sudo apt-key add Release.key

$ gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ stretch main
deb http://http.debian.net/debian stretch-backports main

$ sudo apt-get update
```

However when I'm trying to:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

It says unable to locate winehq-stable. It also says the same to winehq-stable, wine-stable and other various combinations. Typing only wine worked, but it was version 1.8.7-2 ([DXVK](https://github.com/lutris/lutris/wiki/How-to:-DXVK) requires 3.10 or newer) so I purged it. Where do I get the correct package?

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397).

Comment: May the name be [Wine-Staging](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine-Staging)?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian or more precisely the [apt command doesn't support https](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90227/why-there-is-no-https-transport-for-debian-apt-tool) repositories by default.

You'll need to install `apt-transport-https` package in order to access https repositories through apt. Alternatively just use a different mirror for the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Could you post your `apt-get update` results? 
I'm guessing it does not sync the repos correctly so that's why you end up with winehq-stable package not being found in the first place.

As for compiling it depends on what you want to do with wine.
Every thing stated in your terminal output won't work.
You may want to check out the [wine wiki on building](https://wiki.winehq.org/Building_Wine) in case you didn't already. You can probably install most of the needed libraries by installing  wine-development from debian repos.

Keep in mind that you also need to build 32bit version of wine if you want to run 32bit windows software via wine (most likely). [Source](https://wiki.winehq.org/Building_Wine#Shared_WoW64)

Comment: Yep, that was it, there was a failed to fetch error. Fixed it by installing **apt-transport-https**. Could've probably just changed the source to http form, but whatever it works now.