# Pop!_os not proprely connecting to https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease

Tags: apt

Pop!_os wants to update packages but it can't properly fetch updates from https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease

Detailed Error:

```
Failed to fetch https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease
Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (91.189.88.152). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (91.189.88.142). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
```

How do i Fix this error and what causes it?

Comment: Yes i edited sources.list.

Comment: My pop release is 20.04 focal

Comment: so thats the problem

Comment: Thanks! It fixed my problem!

Comment: @Dumpling Welcome to U&L! The system here identified "solved" Questions by upvoted and/or accepted Answers. If you click the checkmark next to the Answer below, that will "solve" your problem. There's no need to update the titles for this activity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding the repository to the sources.list, you added the URL to securely connect to the Ubuntu repository with `https`, but the repository does not support secure connection over TLS. They consider it enough that all packages are already signed, so you should use `http` instead.

[It doesn't mean that apt doesn't support connection over TLS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/90227/423679), but that particular repository does not support TLS connection anyway. You can verify it by trying the URL in a browser.