# Debian: How does apt verify downloaded packages?

Tags: linux, debian, apt, gpg

I can see from my firewall that apt is downloading packages using http. Considering this is an insecure protocol, how does apt verify the integrity of the downloaded package?

Comment: Hello We'll See. This is rather close to a request for documentation - which is off topic here. Do you have a specific question that's on-topic for U&L?

Comment: Hi :), thanks for your comment, have edited to make the question more direct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why there is no https transport for debian apt tool?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90227/why-there-is-no-https-transport-for-debian-apt-tool) essentially https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90321/70524